# Finding number of dlopen calls of an ELF binary in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, elf

I would like to analyze an ELF binary file and figure out how many calls to dlopen() it makes in C, are there any libraries that can do this? Or how would I go about finding the count?

Comment: *You* want to analyze, or you want write a program that will analyze?

Comment: I would like to write a program that analyzes, and was wondering if there were any library calls I could make in C given a binary file that would output the number of calls

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking? How many call points, or how many calls it makes when run? The latter can't be determined in general without running it, either natively or via some sort of interpretation/emulation; the reasons are related to the halting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `ltrace`:

Example:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int C, char **V)
{
    char **a = V+1;
    while(*a){
        void *h;
        if(0==(h=dlopen(*a++, RTLD_LAZY)))
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }

}
```

Compile it:

```
$ gcc example.c -fpic -pie
```

Invoke it on self and count `dlopen` calls:

```
$ ltrace -o /dev/fd/3 \ 
  ./a.out ./a.out ./a.out ./a.out 3>&1 >/dev/null| \
  grep ^dlopen\( -c
3
```

Answer (score 0):

solutions depend on the operating system and boil down to hotpatching the target process. you want to look at systemtap userspace tracing on linux ( https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/userspace-probing.html ) or dtrace on bsd-related systems (like osx). No clue about windows, but they presumably have an equivalent.